# I wanted to put a UIImage into a SKtexture in so that Could Output it in the Node, However getting bad access code 1 swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift-playground, sktexture

I tried to turn the UIImage into SKtexture in Swift playground. However, I get the following error in the below picture. Any help would be appreciated.

[Picture with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wrxB.png)